# howto add facebook friends automatically, or ad likes to your site

Tags: facebook, automation, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-like

Can you describe ways, how user can add friends automatically?
I know there are tools like Facebook Friend Adder!How they works, which functionality have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook API does not have an option to add friends / send friend requests.